# How to subset a dataframe where a column 'contains' the contents of a vector

Tags: r

I have a data frame DF as such:

```
ID  name     description
1   Jen      brooklyn new york cqre center
2   Chris    santa monica barbers
3   Jeff     chicago blah blah
4   Steve    groomers are here
5   Mary     chicken time
6   John     and here we go
```

I would like to remove the rows containing city names.  I have a vector containing city names (cityVec) but this does not work.

f <- DF[grep(paste(cityVec), DF$description, ignore.case=TRUE),]

Comment: try `DF[-grep(paste(cityVec,collapse="|"), DF$description, ignore.case=TRUE),]`

Comment: I get the following error: Error in grep(paste(cityVec, collapse = "|"), DF$description, ignore.case = TRUE) : 
  regular expression is invalid in this locale

Comment: you possibly have such characters in your data `"é"`, can you confirm please

Comment: I think the problem is that it's a vector. Grep works for individual character strings, but vectors that contain strings so not seem to work

Comment: See my answer below and it's same as @jdharrison's, `grep` does work on vector of strings, could you post output of  `str(DF)`, `grep` will not work if `DF$description` is a factor

Comment: @Cybernetic: Your guesses about what does and doesn't work are not very credible. You explanation about how `grep` works is simple wrong. Please heed good advice when it is offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forking data input from jdharrison answer, grep works as you can see on vector of strings

```
description = list(c("brooklyn", "new york", "cqre center")
                   , c("santa monica", "barbers")
                   , c("chicago", "blah blah")
                   , c("groomers", "are here")
                   , c("chicken time")
                   , c("and", "here we go"))

DF <- data.frame(ID = 1:6, name = letters[1:6], description = I(description))

cityVec <- c("chicago", "new york", "paris", "santa monica") 
myDF[-grep(paste(cityVec,collapse="|"), myDF$description, ignore.case=TRUE),]
#  ID name  description
#4  4    d groomers....
#5  5    e chicken time
#6  6    f and, her....
```

Comment: lovely use of `|` there.

Comment: Both these methods result in memory errors. It might work on small datasets but large data frames seem to have a problem with the approach.

Comment: what are the memory errors you face with these methods, could you update your post. Some one with experience with big memory handling might help you out

Comment: I believe it was the ill-formed vector after-all.  Took a while to find the bad characters in such a large vector. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I am assumming your data.frame has a list for `description` if not please use `dput`. You can use sapply to search each element and check if it contains a city or not

```
description = list(c("brooklyn", "new york", "cqre center")
                   , c("santa monica", "barbers")
                   , c("chicago", "blah blah")
                   , c("groomers", "are here")
                   , c("chicken time")
                   , c("and", "here we go"))

myDF <- data.frame(ID = 1:6, name = letters[1:6], description = I(description))

cityVec <- c("chicago", "new york", "paris", "santa monica")                
> myDF[sapply(myDF$description, function(x){!any(x%in%cityVec)}), ]
ID name  description
4  4    d groomers....
5  5    e chicken time
6  6    f and, her....
```